# SSRS Expression - Space Between Dates in Cheque Printing

Tags: xml, reporting-services, microsoft-dynamics, ssrs-2008-r2

My date field `Fields!DateStr.Value` gives a date as `12 March 2015`.

I converted this so that I can use it to print a cheque which has different blocks or squares for each digit of the date.

My expression is -

```
=Format(CDate(Fields!DateStr.Value),"dd")+" "+Format(CDate(Fields!DateStr.Value),"MM")+"    "+Format(CDate(Fields!DateStr.Value),"yy")
```

Which returns:

```
12 03 15
```

But still it's not fitting in the cheque blocks

What I want it to return

```
1  2  0  3  1  5
```

Please can any one help me thought this I have already tried split & trim but they are now working for me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this Code:

---

In SSRS:

```
=Left(Format(CDate(Today()),"dd"),1)+" "+Right(Format(CDate(Today()),"dd"),1)+" "+Left(Format(CDate(Today()),"MM"),1)+" "+Right(Format(CDate(Today()),"MM"),1)+" "+Left(Format(CDate(Today()),"yy"),1)+" "+Right(Format(CDate(Today()),"yy"),1)
```

replace `Today()` with you Field `Fields!DateStr.Value`

---

In SQL:

```
declare @Date varchar(10)=  REPLACE(Convert(varchar,getdate(),105),'-','')

DECLARE @postition INT, @result VARCHAR(100); 
   
   SET @result = REPLACE(Convert(varchar,getdate(),105),'-','')
   SET @postition = 2 -- location where we want first space 
   WHILE @postition < LEN(@result)+1 
   BEGIN 
       SET @result = STUFF(@result, @postition, 0, SPACE(1)); 
       SET @postition = @postition+2; 
   END 
   Print @result;
```

you can also use above sql code as a sql function.